# Get content asset by language id

Tags: e-commerce, demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I'm using Saleforce.com system to develop website, in default site I call `<iscontentasset aid="logo"/>` and It's work. In admin page, I Select Language is English and in my code I want to call `<iscontentasset aid="logo" language="en" />` but it's not working. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an SFRA project, make sure you have included this template

```
<isinclude template="/components/modules" sf-toolkit="off" />
```

before using

For SG, make sure to include modules template where iscontentasset tag is declared for more details, follow below docs.

[SFCC Docs](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/isml/b2c_ismodule.html?resultof=%22%69%73%6D%6F%64%75%6C%65%22%20%22%69%73%6D%6F%64%75%6C%22%20)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no such possibility out of the box.
`<iscontentasset aid="asset_id" />` tag itself is just another custom extension for .isml templates which is represented by `dw.content.ContentMgr.getContent(parameter)` under the hood.
You can't get a localized content asset just like that cause SFCC returns localizable elements considering `request.locale` attribute whilst getting from DB

Comment: does it translate in whole page? and it can not translate in every content asset.

Answer (score 1):

You can set request.setLocale(‘en_US’) before accessing the content asset and within content asset you can add locale specific content. After that you can reset the locale.